# How to literally translate this: 极爱冒险的大导演...?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

据说，曾经有一位很有个性、极爱冒险的大导演到南美丛林拍有关古代印加文明的纪录片。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 26. About its literal translation, I have reached to the following point:

据说 (it is said that)，曾经(once)有(there was)一(a)位(classifier)很有(very having)个性(individuality)、极(very or extremely)爱(loving)冒险(to take risks)的大(big)导演(director)到(arrived to or went to)南美(South America)丛林(jungle)拍(to take)有关(being related to or having relation to)古代(ancient)印加(Inca)文明(civilization)的纪录片(documentary)。

To me, everything makes sense, apart from this: 极爱冒险的大导演.

Two specific questions:

1. What is your opinion about this: 极(very or extremely)爱(loving)冒险(to take risks)? Is there a better literal translation?
2. 大导演 means big director in age (old director) or very famous (great) director? How should I act when I see the word 大?

Answer (score 2):

1. 极爱冒险: your literal translation is fine. I would translate it as "very adventurous."
2. 大 usually takes the sense of "famous" or "great," to express "old" we would use 老.

Answer (score 2):

大 has a number of meanings in Chinese, depending on the context. Some examples:

大石 - a big rock

大陸 - continent (or Mainland China)

大人 - an adult

大人物 - famous person

大官 - a senior government official

大猩猩 - not a large ape but a gorilla (very specific)

大學 - university

As for 冒险, it generally means adventure(s) or adventurous in modern usage.

Answer (score 1):

极爱冒险的大导演

极: 极其: extremely
爱: 热爱: love ardently

冒险: adventure
大导演: great film-director